# doubleWidth and doubleHeight in span doesn't linebreak HTML

Tags: html, css

I have the following predefined HTML with some css styles. I am trying to print a text in a predifined width, as you can see bellow the line breaks when the text reaches the maximum width.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>@font-face {
    font-family: MyFont;
    src: url("file:///android_asset/printer/fonts/DroidSansMono.ttf")
}
<style>
div{
}
 span{
    word-wrap:break-word;
     white-space: normal;
}

 .doubleHeight {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(2);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(2);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(2);
    -o-transform: scaleY(2);
    transform: scaleY(2);
       display: inline-block;
} 
 
 .origin {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
} 

 .doubleWidth {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(2);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(2);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(2);
    -o-transform: scaleX(2);
    transform: scaleX(2);
     display: inline-block;
}  
.container{
    background:red;
    letter-spacing:-2.3px;
    width: 372px;
     font-family: MyFont;
    font-size:19px;}
 

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class = container>
<span class="">DOUBLE&nbsp;WIDTH&nbsp;TEXT&nbsp;DOUBLE&nbsp;WIDTH&nbsp;TEXT&nbsp;DOUBLE&nbsp;WIDTH&nbsp;TEXT&nbsp;DOUBLE&nbsp;WIDTH&nbsp;TEXT</span><br>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I apply doubleWidth to the text I don't understand why the line doesn't break when the line reaches the maximum width, like in the example bellow.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>@font-face {
    font-family: MyFont;
    src: url("file:///android_asset/printer/fonts/DroidSansMono.ttf")
}
<style>
div{
}
 span{
    word-wrap:break-word;
     white-space: normal;
}

 .doubleHeight {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(2);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(2);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(2);
    -o-transform: scaleY(2);
    transform: scaleY(2);
       display: inline-block;
} 
 
 .origin {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
} 

 .doubleWidth {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(2);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(2);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(2);
    -o-transform: scaleX(2);
    transform: scaleX(2);
     display: inline-block;
}  
.container{
    background:red;
    letter-spacing:-2.3px;
    width: 372px;
     font-family: MyFont;
    font-size:19px;}
 

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class = container>
<span class="origin doubleWidth">DOUBLE&nbsp;WIDTH&nbsp;TEXT&nbsp;DOUBLE&nbsp;WIDTH&nbsp;TEXT&nbsp;DOUBLE&nbsp;WIDTH&nbsp;TEXT&nbsp;DOUBLE&nbsp;WIDTH&nbsp;TEXT</span><br>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If somenone can help me, I am new to HTML and don't understant why this happens. Thank you

Ps: the same thing happen with double height

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Problem is caused by using `display: inline-block;` on the SPAN element. Inline block elements scale to fit the childrens' widths whereas block elements wrap the children elements to fit into it. So it should be `span.doubleWidth { display: block; }` or change the SPAN to DIV.

Comment: The `scale()` commands are applied after the element's width and height have been calculated. You will therefore need to add a bit of JS code to handle width and height calculation. For an inspiration see [this post](https://davidwalsh.name/get-element-dimensions-css-transform).